# WPF LiveChart 2 данные из графика в label

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Как при использовании библиотеки **LiveCharts 2** для **WPF** выводить значения *оси Y* графиков в label или другой объект для отображения текста?

В примере обрисовывается два графика

```
public ISeries[] Series { get; set; } =
    {
        new LineSeries<double>
        {
            Values = new ObservableCollection<double> { 200, 558, 458, 249, 457, 339, 587 },
        },
        new LineSeries<double>
        {
            Values = new ObservableCollection<double> { 210, 400, 300, 350, 219, 323, 618 },
        },
    };
```

И настраивается Crosshair

```
public Axis[] XAxes { get; set; } =
    {
        new Axis
        {
            CrosshairLabelsBackground = SKColors.DarkOrange.AsLvcColor(),
            CrosshairLabelsPaint = new SolidColorPaint(SKColors.DarkRed, 1),
            CrosshairPaint = new SolidColorPaint(SKColors.DarkOrange, 1),
            Labeler = value => value.ToString("N2")
        }
    };
    public Axis[] YAxes { get; set; } =
    {
        new Axis
        {
            CrosshairLabelsBackground = SKColors.DarkOrange.AsLvcColor(),
            CrosshairLabelsPaint = new SolidColorPaint(SKColors.DarkRed, 1),
            CrosshairPaint = new SolidColorPaint(SKColors.DarkOrange, 1),
            CrosshairSnapEnabled = true // snapping is also supported
        }
    };
```

Как при перемещении курсора по графику отображать и изменять текс label указывая в нём значение точек конкретного графика?
[image: Пример графика]

Comment: https://v0.lvcharts.com/App/examples/v1/Wpf/Events